# VSCode C/C++ Intellisense and Windows specific libraries

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am experimenting with some Windows specific libraries in C++ (Using C libraries in my C++ code). I am trying to include `objbase.h` for `CoCreateInstance()` function:

```
#include <objbase.h>
// ...
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(/* ... */);
```

My problem is with the VSCode C/C++ extension's intellisense. The code compiles ok, but the intellisense has some problems identifying this function. It has no problem with `HRESULT`, but for `CoCreateInstance()` it shows `"identifier is undefined"`.

So I tried to look into the header file itself and figured out, the problem is, that the intellisense is recognizing some errors in the file and not letting me use the function, since it thinks it is not declared properly. It has no problem with the `HRESULT`, because it's just some simple `typedef`, that it understands. However the `CoCreateInstance()` is declared as:

```
WINOLEAPI CoCreateInstance( //...
```

where `WINOLEAPI` is a macro containing something like:

```
extern __declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall
```

I assume `__declspec` and `__stdcall` are some Windows specific keywords, and that the intellisense is simply not recognizing those, detecting an error, which makes the function undeclared, hence the `"identifier is undefined"` error.

Is this the cause of the problem? If so, is there any way to "teach" the intellisense something about those windows specific keywords? After all it is a Microsoft extension, I have no idea, why it wouldn't recognize Microsoft's C language extensions.

### Update

I have found a temporary fix. See my answer below.

### Update: Clarification

It seems that both `combaseapi.h` and `objbase.h` include all the dependencies they need, as even the intellisense is able to recognize `__declspec` (and `__stdcall`) as some `"int __declspec"` but it is unable to understand the syntax, where the type is surrounded by other keywords. It gives me an "explicit type is missing" error on the `WINOLEAPI` macro. When I replace the macro with its value explicitly as `"extern __declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall"`, it gives me errors like `"missing ;"`. So it seems, that it doesn't understand such syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a temporary workaround. The `WINOLEAPI` macro is defined in the `combaseapi.h` file. I added these lines to the file after the `WINOLEAPI` definition:

```
// Original content of the file:
#ifdef _OLE32_
#define WINOLEAPI STDAPI
#define WINOLEAPI_(type) STDAPI_(type)
#else
#define WINOLEAPI EXTERN_C DECLSPEC_IMPORT HRESULT STDAPICALLTYPE
#define WINOLEAPI_(type) EXTERN_C DECLSPEC_IMPORT type STDAPICALLTYPE
#endif

// Added fix for VSCode intellisense:
#ifdef __INTELLISENSE__
#define WINOLEAPI EXTERN_C HRESULT
#define WINOLEAPI_(type) EXTERN_C type
#endif
```

Now when `__INTELLISENSE__` is defined (It is not defined when compiling the code, but only when the intellisense examines the file.), it removes the unrecognized keywords from `WINOLEAPI` macro.

It would be nice though to apply some similar fix inside my code instead of modifying the included header. Also, this fixes only this particular situation, any of the other unsupported keywords must be treated separately. In my case, it fixes all problems in those two header files.

It works, but I would still appreciate if anyone provided some better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Add `#include <windows.h>` above objbaseapi.h

windows.h includes required definitions like for `HRESULT` ( Actually from winerror.h, but including windows.h should take care of it's dependents etc)

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work. I edited my question with clarification of the errors in the header files. It's probably not a problem of missing dependencies headers.